# Horizontally center current page in flexbox pagination

Tags: css, flexbox

Given the following navigation examples:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body > * + * {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

a {
  display: block;
  color: #0B2545;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}

a:hover {
  background: #EEF4ED;
}

ol {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li:first-child,
li:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

li:first-child a,
li:last-child a {
  width: max-content;
}

li:last-child a {
  margin-left: auto;
}

li.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}

li.active a {
  background: #8DA9C4;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">previous</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4000</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">next</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">previous</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4000</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">next</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">previous</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">500</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4000</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">next</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">previous</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">3999</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4000</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">next</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">previous</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">...</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">4000</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">next</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Is it possible to position the active element so that it's always horizontally centered, keeping the same "distance" to its siblings like now, without using JavaScript, setting fixed widths or targeting a specific element number (`nth-child`) in the CSS? I cannot use any containers to wrap elements either.

Edit: The result should look like this:

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aov1d.png)

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/gqnLt0yj/ ? or you want all elements to be pushed as well ? Maybe be more specific in your question.

Comment: Thanks, but your example does not meet the "keeping the same "distance" to its siblings like now" requirement.